# Buildroot - Enabling Qt5 WebKit

Tags: qt, webkit, qt5, buildroot

I am trying to build a RFS for imx6 based system using buildroot and I want to add qt webkit to my system so that my software which has written on Qt5 and used webenginewidgets will run. However, when I enable qt5webkit under qt5 in buildroot, buildroot gives me the following error.

```
/home/mkp/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/qt5webkit-b35917bcb44d7f200af0f4ac68a126fa0aa8d93d/Source/WebCore//libWebCore.a: member /home/mkp/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/qt5webkit-b35917bcb44d7f200af0f4ac68a126fa0aa8d93d/Source/WebCore//.obj/svg/SVGAllInOne.o in archive is not an object
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.6.2] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/mkp/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/qt5webkit-b35917bcb44d7f200af0f4ac68a126fa0aa8d93d/Source'
make[2]: *** [sub-api-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mkp/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/qt5webkit-b35917bcb44d7f200af0f4ac68a126fa0aa8d93d/Source'
make[1]: *** [sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mkp/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/qt5webkit-b35917bcb44d7f200af0f4ac68a126fa0aa8d93d'
make: *** [/home/mkp/buildroot-2016.11/output/build/qt5webkit-b35917bcb44d7f200af0f4ac68a126fa0aa8d93d/.stamp_built] Error 2
```

Something wrong about SVGAllInOne.cpp or .o but, I could not figure it out.
BTW, buildroot is up-to-date.

Comment: What version of Qt are you running?

Comment: As I see from the packages which is downloaded by buildroot, it seems qt 5.6.2

Answer (score -1):

Stack Overflow is not the appropriate place to report bugs. Please report them in the Buildroot bug tracker, including the exact Buildroot configuration file that you have used to produce this problem, so that Buildroot developers can reproduce and investigate the issue. Thanks!

Comment: It may not be a bug. I asked here so if there is someone may encounter about this kind of a problem. Nevertheless, thank you for paying attention.